# JQuery: Dynamic Form Won't Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that i append to a top of a table to add a new row but for some reason I can't capture the submit event.  The row shows just fine at the top of the table with the form input elements.

```
$("#btn_addrow").on("click", function () {
    $("#tbl_list").prepend("<tr><form id='frm_add'><td><input type='text' name='date'> </td><td><input type='text' name='note'></td><td><input type='submit' value='add row'></td></form></tr>");

});
```

I can't get this event to trigger:

```
$("body").on("submit", "#frm_add", function (event){
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('test');
   /* $.ajax function will go here to save row */
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working, see: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9A6pf/), however instead of inserting forms with ID's you should insert forms with class. ID should be unique all the time, so I will do like this:

```
$("#btn_addrow").on("click", function () {
    $("#tbl_list").prepend("<tr><form class='frm_add'><td><input type='text' name='date'> </td><td><input type='text' name='note'></td><td><input type='submit' value='add row'></td></form></tr>");

});

$("body").on("submit", ".frm_add", function (event){
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('test');
   /* $.ajax function will go here to save row */
});
```

**UPDATE**

The code will not work in Firefox, due to a firefox bug, or call it what ever you want. To get this code working, you can do the following, add and ID or some sort of identifier to your table, wrap the new row into the form, instead of wrapping the form in the row, and use jQuery insertAfter method to inject the new form in the DOM.

Please see an updated example here: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9A6pf/3/), and the code should look similar to this:

```
$("#btn_addrow").on("click", function () {
 $("<form class='frm_add'><tr><td><input type='text' name='date'> </td><td><input type='text' name='note'></td><td><input type='submit' value='add row'></td></tr></form>").insertAfter($("#my_table"));

});

$("body").on("submit", ".frm_add", function (event){
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('test');
   /* $.ajax function will go here to save row */
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice with the classes.  I did check the fiddle example but it doesn't show the alert box when the add row button is clicked.  Still seems like its not triggering the submit event.

Comment: What browser are you using? I never post a fiddle before testing it, and it's definitely working on my computer. Let me check it with some other browsers as well, at the moment I'm using chrome

Comment: I'm using firefox.  I just tried with chrome and the fiddle example does show the alert box.

Comment: I just tried it now in firefox and I see your problem, that is very strange

Comment: I may just drop the form idea and just use a normal button and on the click event, just grab the input values and put them into the ajax call.

Comment: That is one possibility, the other one is to add a class to the submit button and attach the listener to that like here: http://jsfiddle.net/9A6pf/1/ , but I'm very curious, why it is not working in firefox.

Comment: I may go with your class idea so I can do $(form).serialize() to send over my form data easily in my ajax call.  Thanks for checking into this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47770/discussion-between-emil-borconi-and-ralph)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add action attribute to the form:

```
<form action=""></form>
```

So you can update your code to:

```
$("#btn_addrow").on("click", function () {
    $("#tbl_list").prepend("<tr><form action="" id='frm_add'><td><input type='text' name='date'> </td><td><input type='text' name='note'></td><td><input type='submit' value='add row'></td></form></tr>");
});
```

Comment: Just tried adding the action attribute, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `ajax` call, Then you can just change your `submit button` to `simple button` and bind your method to it. Just keep in mind you have to bind the method after the control is added to `DOM`.

```
$("#btn_addrow").on("click", function () {
    $("#tbl_list").prepend("<tr><form id='frm_add'><td><input type='text' name='date'> </td><td><input type='text' name='note'></td><td><input type='button' id='btnSubmit' value='add row'></td></form></tr>");

$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){  
       event.preventDefault();
       alert('test');
       /* $.ajax function will go here to save row */
    });

});
```

And I haven't tried but may be moving your `event binding` to or after the `control generation method` would work.